# Cannot read property 'value' of null (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Решил попробовать изучить JavaScript. У меня есть текстовое поле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
с ID "login-area"

И кнопка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
с ID "click-button"

Попробовал на JS получить текст поля при нажатии на кнопку и вывести текст в консоль:

login.js:

```
document.getElementById('click-button').onclick = click();
function click()
{
    'use strict';
    var Login = document.getElementById('login-area').value;
    console.log(Login);
}
```

Но мне выдавало ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде несколько проблем:

1. Лишний вызов функции

   ```
   document.getElementById('click-button').onclick = click();
   ```

   в данном случае, не нужны `()` так как нужна сама функция, а не результат ее вызова
2. ошибка в заголовке относится к строке

   ```
   var Login = document.getElementById('login-area').value;
   ```

   это говорит о том, что в момент выполнения данной функции элемента еще нет на странице.

Вполне вероятно, что при исправлении первого пункта, автоматически исправится и второй, так как вызов обработчика будет происходить когда вся разметка уже будет доступна.

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо!